# jenkins hang up: Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work

Tags: jenkins, apache

I was trying to run jenkins in my server, but always I have the same message, and wait and wait and nothing. In the official website they report about this problem, but I wanted to ask if someone know how to fix it, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

because for me was a little tricky take the solution, I'll post my own answer, now its working:

Finally I ran jenkins by hand, by using the war with the next command in linux, not by using the services ("service jenkins start"):

```
java -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --httport=8081 --aj13port=8081 --prefix=/jenkins
```